# Copy multiple files from HTTP to Blob in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, file, http, web, copy

***Disregard.
Below requirement is changed to only copy one file. File naming convention is: "somestring_yesterdaysDate.xml". Last modified time of the file remains today's date within the first hour. So the file to be copied today would be "somestring_20230308.xml" with a modified date of 20230309 at around 12:03 AM.

### I will update in the comments once figured this out.

I am trying to move multiple files (csv and xml) from a public HTTP site into Blob Storage account in ADF. The pipeline I am using has a Copy Activity that uses a linked service (binary file) and data set. However, I can only copy one file by providing the filename in the URL.

Question I have is there a way to copy all files from the URL given the scenario.

Note that filenames will change daily in an inconsistent manner therefore using a test file containing filenames as an input is not an option. Filenames should also persist once copied to the blob.

Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned that 'filenames will change daily in an inconsistent manner', but how are you giving single a file name in the URL where the file names changes daily? How do you know which file name should be given in the URL? and can you give a sample URL with file name?

Comment: @concat('SomeString_', formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(), -1), 'yyyyMMdd'), '.xml'). This fulfills the requirement I was looking for.

Comment: @odbods - which linked service do you use to load the source file via URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your first requirement, i.e, copying multiple files might not be possible as you don't know the exact files which you are copying. If the file names contains dates and every file is coming daily, then you can generate a date range array and pass it to a ForEach. Inside ForEach use copy activity with `@item()` to it with dataset parameter.

> Below requirement is changed to only copy one file. File naming convention is: "somestring_yesterdaysDate.xml". Last modified time of the file remains today's date within the first hour. So the file to be copied today would be "somestring_20230308.xml" with a modified date of 20230309 at around 12:03 AM

This can be done using the below dynamic content as mentioned by you in comments.
`@concat('SomeString_', formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(), -1), 'yyyyMMdd'), '.xml')`.

**My sample:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

You can also use the below expression to achieve the same:

```
@concat('somestring_',formatDateTime(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'yyyyMMdd'),'.xml')
```

**getPastTime()** function returns the current Timestamp (in UTC) minus the specified unit. **formatDateTime()** function returns the value in the specified date format.

Comment: Thanks Naveen. I tried your last suggested expression and can confirm that it returns expected output.

As for my original requirement (retracted later), unfortunately I don't have time to go back to it and test it for daily files with date in their names. However, I may try it out if I get some downtime.